# phi instruction semantics in llvm-IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Trying to understand phi instruction semantics in llvm-IR

(https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#phi-instruction)

Let's consider the following example:

```
 ; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind
 define i32 @main( i32 %argc, i8** %argv) {
 entry:
   switch  i32 %argc, label %L1 [ i32 0, label %L0
                                  i32 1, label %L1 ]
 L0:
   %x = add i32 %argc, 1
   br label %L1
 L1:
    %y = phi i32 [ %argc, %entry ], [ %x, %L0 ]
    %z = sub i32 %y, 1
   %w = udiv i32 100, %z
   ret i32 %w
 }
```

Compilation with clang-7.0.1

```
 $ clang-7.0.1 -O0 test.ll -o a.out
 PHINode should have one entry for each predecessor of its parent basic
 block!
 %y = phi i32 [ %argc, %entry ], [ %x, %L0 ]
 fatal error: error in backend: Broken function found, compilation
```

aborted!

When I replaced "%y = phi ..." by "%y = add i32 2, 1" the test was compiled successfully.

The question here is about error message:
why not all predecessors are listed in phi in the test? From description of phi instruction in LangRef.html#phi-instruction I can't
understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there are multiple edges from block A to block B, then the PHI nodes in B must list A as many times as there are edges, each time with the same value. In your case there are two edges from `entry` to `L1` (one for the default case of the switch and one for the 1 case), so `entry` needs to be listed twice in the PHI node.

But perhaps the cleaner solution in this case would be to just remove the `[i32 1, label %L1]` case from your switch as that's redundant anyway. Then there'd only be one edge and you'd only need one entry for `entry`.

Comment: Thank you, very much! Now I got it.